# Phoenix endpoint config - Force HTTPS with multiple subomdains

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm setting up a Phoenix app that is serving more than one subdomain from the same endpoint. All it does is use a plug to select a different router at the end of the endpoint plugs depending on the subdomain of the request. That's all working OK.

The issue is with the `force_ssl` configuration.

My endpoint configuration looks like the following:

```
config :frontend, Frontend.Endpoint,
  on_init: {Frontend.Endpoint, :load_from_system_env, []},
  url: [scheme: "https", host: "myapp.com", port: 443],
  force_ssl: [rewrite_on: [:x_forwarded_proto]],
  cache_static_manifest: "priv/static/cache_manifest.json"
```

The host has to just be `myapp.com` as this endpoint configuration applies to all the subdomains.

This configuration is unfortunately causing all requests to `foo.myapp.com` (both HTTP and HTTPS) to be 301 redirected to `https://myapp.com`.

The behavior I want would be to 301:

- `http://foo.myapp.com` to `https://foo.myapp.com`
- `http://bar.myapp.com` to `https://bar.myapp.com`

Requests to `https://foo.myapp.com` and `https://bar.myapp.com` should **not** be getting redirected.

Help would be appreciated! If it is relevant, I'm on Phoenix 1.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [SSL plug source](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/7fbf4fc0567a3276c978b434c4f0c658228af276/lib/phoenix/endpoint.ex#L130-L136):

> To dynamically redirect to the `host` of the current request, `:host`
>   must be set `nil`.

Looks like:

```
config :myapp, MyApp.Endpoint,
  force_ssl: [
    host: nil,
    rewrite_on: [:x_forwarded_proto]
  ]
```

Though, using a proxy (i.e., NGINX) will provide far more granular control.